# In TSQL, how to select nodes within a hierarchy?

Tags: t-sql, tree, common-table-expression

I have a table that represents an organizational hierarchy. Simplifying a bit (because the complexity isn't relevant here), imagine the classic bill of materials or management hierarchy, each record has an id and a parent_id, and of course other relevant data, let's just say name. Let's call this table "node".

Then I have records saying which users are authorized to access data about any given node in the hierarchy. Call this node_user.

So I want to find all the node_user records for nodes that are at or below a given node.

Easy enough for a small finite number of levels. Say ...

```
select nu.userid
from node_user nu
join node n1 on n1.id=nu.node_id
left join node n2 on n2.id=n1.parent_id
left join node n3 on n3.id=n2.parent_id
where @root in (n1.id, n2.id, n3.id)
```

But what if I don't know the maximum depth or it's large? I was thinking I could do the "chase up the tree" using a CTE, doing a "from node_user join (with hierarchy ...)", but that's a syntax error. Apparently you can't use a CTE as a sub-query. But I can't make the CTE the main query because I don't know what nodes I'll find. Unless I make the CTE build a tree for the entire database, which I would think would be a performance killer.

Is there an easy way to do this and I'm just having a brain freeze?

Comment: You are probably just having a brain freesze. A recursive cte is the way to solve id...parent_id queries. If you could [edit] your post to provide sample data as ddl+dml and desired results, it will make it much easier to answer.

Comment: It sounds like you want to walk the tree with a recursive CTE from the given `node` all the way to the leaves, then `join` the result with `node_user` to get the applicable rows. No need to walk the entire hierarchy if you have a specific starting point. (Don't forget the `MaxRecursion` hint if the depth will exceed the default of 100.)

Comment: @habo Yeah, I was thinking along those lines as I was eating lunch. Maybe I'm doing this backwards. Instead of finding the node_user records and then walking up the tree to see if I find the root, I should walk down the tree from root and then look for matching node_user records.

Comment: @Jay Your question says "at or below a given node." Start at that node (`select ... where node_id = @initial_node_id`), recursively find its children (`... union all select ... where cte.node_id = bom.parent_id`), `join` the CTE result with `node_user` and Bob's your uncle. If you posted DDL and sample data ... .

Comment: See Example D in https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/queries/with-common-table-expression-transact-sql?view=sql-server-2017#d-using-a-recursive-common-table-expression-to-display-multiple-levels-of-recursion Change `WHERE ManagerID IS NULL` to `WHERE ManagerID=@DesiredManagerID`.